# Correct implementation of SearchView in android toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

I have a problem with searchview implementation in android toolbar.

1. The empty space padding is too big.
2. I don't want to hide other actions, but these actions are
   overlapped by SearchView.
3. SearchView's underline is not visible

How do i fix issues mentioned above ?

[image]

*menu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/car_num"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_client"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_multiple_plus"
        android:title="@string/action_add_client"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

*fragment*

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_reg_vehicles, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, item, true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setItemsVisibility(menu, item, false);
            searchView.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That is why i always build app use linearlayout to setup toolbar instead of build in toolbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your posted code, this is the output:

[image: Toolbar with SearchView AppCompat by default]

As you can see, there is two left margins: the widget's container and the magnify icon. This is why you have an empty space bigger than an another window with a title. And the menu items are pushed outside the toolbar which, I think, it's the default SearchView `ActionView` when it's not a `CollapseActionView` so it fills the parent.

From the source of `SearchView` widget and its layout [abc_search_view.xml](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml), I tried to remove the extra margins and avoid pushing the other items outside the toolbar.
But after many manipulations, my guess is you have to use a custom widget and/or a custom layout. Or to play with `setIconifiedByDefault(true)` which removes the magnify icon and its extra margin and to use `setMaxWidth(MAX_SIZE)` where `MAX_SIZE` is calculated dynamically by `Integer.MAX_VALUE - (SIZE_OF_A_MENU_ITEM * NB_OF_MENU_ITEMS)`... But it requires a lot of work for nothing. So using a custom layout could be the solution.

However, **there is a possible way to keep the appcompat widget**, some little workarounds. First, to avoid puhsing out the other items, you can use the `CollapseActionView`.

```
<item
    ...
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
```

And to maintain your requirements, you have to expand it when you initialize it:

```
final SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(item);
```

*Be aware that you have to use `setOnActionExpandListener()` in order to close the window if you don't want to collapse the item.* This suggestion will give you this result:

[image: Toolbar with SearchView AppCompat expanded]

Still the extra margins, right? Therefore, you have to retrieve the container and the magnify icon by their ids (which you can find in `abc_search_view.xml`... but let's save some time: they are `R.id.search_edit_frame` and `R.id.search_mag_icon`). You can remove their margins by using this method:

```
private void changeSearchViewElements(View view) {
    if (view == null) 
        return;

    if (view.getId() == R.id.search_edit_frame
            || view.getId() == R.id.search_mag_icon) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = 
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.leftMargin = 0; // set no left margin
        view.setLayoutParams(p);
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            changeSearchViewElements(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

By calling it in a thread:

```
final SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
...
searchView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            changeSearchViewElements(searchView);
        }
    });
```

Here's the output:

[image: Toolbar with SearchView AppCompat without left margin]

Finally, to get the line under the field, there is a possible workaround as using a 9-patch drawable and set it as a background. You can easily find how-to on Google. So the condition will be:

```
private void changeSearchViewElements(View view) {
    ...
    if (view.getId() == R.id.search_edit_frame
            || view.getId() == R.id.search_mag_icon) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = 
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.leftMargin = 0; // set no left margin
        view.setLayoutParams(p);

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.search_src_text) {
        AutoCompleteTextView searchEdit = (AutoCompleteTextView) view;
        searchEdit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect_underline_white);
    }
    ...
}
```

From the OP's comment below, the underline's field can also be done with the following statement:

```
searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.se‌​arch_src_text)
        .setBa‌​ckgroundResource(R.d‌​rawable.abc_textfiel‌​d_search_default_mtr‌​l_alpha);
```

---

After these workarounds, as I said, it might be easier to use a custom layout. But if you want to keep the default SearchView widget, this might help.

Comment: also to fix 3rd issue, I added following line `searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha);`

Comment: Good to know, thanks for sharing it, I add it to this answer. Thanks